# Python - Azure SQL slow insert vs local database

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert 200,000 rows in Azure SQL database using Python SQLAlchemy.
According to SQLAlchemy [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow) I tried fastest bulk insert methods: bulk_insert_mappings and core.

Yet insert speed is ridiculously low: 100 rows per 7.5 seconds.
When I run the same code using local database, the code inserts 10,000 records in a few seconds.

SQL table I insert to consists of 4 columns:
[Data] ([Date] date, [sId] int , [mId] int, [Value] float) with primary key (Date, sId, mId) and foreign keys sId, mId references reasonably small tables (<10K rows in each).

Any ideas what could be causing such drastic difference between local and Azure SQL db?

- Not DTU issue: Azure SQL database compute utilization <1%, tried 100DTU setup with empty table
- Not networking issue: hosted same code in app service in the same region, performance does not improve

Comment: Have you tried `engine = create_engine(connection_uri, fast_executemany=True)` …?

Comment: Wich is the VM size? There is some max throughput IOPS?

Comment: @GordThompson thank you very much! Adding fast_executemany=True solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for @Gord Thompson.

We could set the [Fast Executemany Mode](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#fast-executemany-mode) in python.

The Pyodbc driver has added support for a “fast executemany” mode of execution which greatly reduces round trips for a DBAPI `executemany()` call when using Microsoft ODBC drivers, for **limited size batches that fit in memory**. The feature is enabled by setting the flag `.fast_executemany` on the DBAPI cursor when an executemany call is to     be used. The SQLAlchemy pyodbc SQL Server dialect supports setting       this flag automatically when the `.fast_executemany` flag is passed to `create_engine()`; note that the ODBC driver must be the Microsoft driver in order to use this flag:

```
 engine = create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@mssql2017:1433/test?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server",
    fast_executemany=True)
```

We are glad that it help you solve the isue.